# Prove that $(B,S)$ is a BSGS, with $B = [1,2]$ and $S = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $B = [1,2]$ and $S = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]$, I want to prove that $(B,S)$ is a Base and a Strong Generating System (BSGS).

According to GAP, $(B,S)$ is indeed a BSGS. But I would like to prove this manually, however I'm not very good at it.

Comment: The group generated by $S$ is $A_4$, which has order $4 \times 3$.

Comment: To prove by hand, you need to find the orbit of 1 and generators for the stabilizer of 1, as the first step